# \mathsmaller does not work inside align*

Tags: math-mode, relsize

Here is a minimum working example

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\denom}{T1}{lmss}{sbc}{n}
\begin{document}
$\denom{C\mathsmaller{ENTI}Meters}$
\begin{align*}
\denom{C\mathsmaller{ENTI}Meters}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I know Arseneau says "*math larger/smaller commands should not be trusted very far, and they will not be useful in every instance*" but I wish somebody could find a workaround.

Comment: it's not particularly related to `align*`: as the relsize comments make clear `\mathsmaller` will use `\textstyle` font in display math, which is the same font as the surrounding text, so you would see the same in `equation` or `\[`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I agree of course. It's just that I wanted to keep things to ... a working minimum.

Comment: for the example that makes sense, but for the question title it's misleading (especially as it's a self answer)

Answer (score 1):

As it happens, almost exactly 10 years ago, I asked the very same question on the OSX TeX list, Frank STENGEL explained what happened and Ross MORE said to: "*include a* `\textstyle` *switch*":

```
{\textstyle\denom{C\mathsmaller{ENTI}}}\;{\textstyle\denom{Meters}}
```

Answer (score 0):

`\mathsmaller` is thought for symbols such as `\sum` and uses `\textstyle` when found in `\displaystyle`:

```
\def\rs@makesmallerchoice{\mathchoice
  {\textstyle \let\rs@sstyle\scriptstyle \rs@mathatom}%
  {\scriptstyle \let\rs@sstyle\scriptstyle \rs@mathatom}%
  {\scriptscriptstyle \let\rs@sstyle\scriptscriptstyle \rs@mathatom}%
  {\scriptscriptstyle \let\rs@sstyle\scriptscriptstyle \rs@mathatom}%
 \egroup}
```

If you want to emulate small caps with a font not having them, use `\text` (and some tricks).

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\fsc}[1]{%
  \begingroup\escapechar=\m@ne
  \xdef\fsc@font{\expandafter\string\the\textfont\mathgroup}%
  \endgroup
  \text{%
    \edef\fsc@size{\f@size}%
    \expandafter\split@name\fsc@font\@nil
    \usefont{\f@encoding}{\f@family}{\f@series}{\f@shape}%
    \fontsize{.7\dimexpr\fsc@size}{\z@}\selectfont
    #1%
  }%
}
\makeatother


\DeclareMathAlphabet{\denom}{T1}{lmss}{sbc}{n}
\begin{document}
$\denom{C\fsc{ENTI}Meters}+\frac{\denom{C\fsc{ENTI}Meters}}{2}$

$\mathrm{C\fsc{ENTI}Meters}$
\[
\denom{C\fsc{ENTI}Meters}+\frac{\denom{C\fsc{ENTI}Meters}}{2}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]